# How to read files from my bin directory in my Tomcat folder in a Spring MVC application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, readfile

How can I read files into an InputStream in my Spring MVC application from the /bin directory in the applications Tomcat folder?

How can I tell what the relative path would be?

Would I need something similar to

```
FileInputStream.class.getResourceAsStream("/bin/FILEHERE.p12");
```

The files I need to read are p12 certificate files.

Comment: If you want to read files you need to open a file not a resource.

Comment: Ok please show me how I can read the file relatively from the tomcat directory and not from my absolute system path.

Comment: `new File("bin/test.txt")` will address a file relative to the start directory of tomcat. This is not spec compliant and not the finest method, but somethiomes you got to do what you got to do.

Comment: When I do that I get java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'bin/MyFile.p12' does not exist but specifying new File("/Users/myname/Desktop/work-tomcats/application/bin/MyFile.p12") does work

Comment: Well, it must be relative to your start dir, not sure what it is in your case. You can use getAbsoluteFile() and print it, it will tell you what it thinks it points to.

Comment: getAbsoluteFile() is a static method on which class? In isolation my compiler says that method does not exist.

Comment: `new File("dummy").getAbsoluteFile()` will return something like `"/opt/tomcat/work/dummy"` in that case you know that `/opt/tomcat/work` was your start dir and you can use `"../bin/MyFile.p12"`. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile%28%29)

Comment: Doing the .. in ../bin/MyFile.p12 worked. Please post an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Fie object with a relative (not starting with `/`) path. This path will be relative to the current work directory of tomcat (typically the start directory the script uses). If it is below the base directory, you can use `..` to navigate upward:

```
File f = new File("../bin/MyFile.p12").getAbsolutFile();
```

Note that accessing files is not spec compliant (also most servlet containers will allow it unless the security manager is enabled). It is a good idea to request it as an absolute file, so any exception "cannot open file" will contain the interpolated path